# Read single json value into a string from jackson objectmapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting below when i try to read single json value into a string, how can i do it ?

```
        String jsonString = "{\"publisher\":\"Test\"}";
        String publisher = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString,
                String.class);

        System.out.println("publisher name : " + publisher);
```

**Error**
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@42f3fe0; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: You're providing an object with one field "publisher" as a json string. So deserializing into a String won't work. See [here for an example](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).